# How to make header with scrollview

Tags: android

I want to make a header in my layout just like below image:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffs6M.jpg)

here my code:-

```
     <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/header_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="5dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:text="@string/filter"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/filter1"
                        android:textSize="16dp"
                        android:id="@+id/textView"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/sort"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:id="@+id/textview_sort"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/sort1"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:textColor="#000"/>



                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView"
                        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/view1"
                        android:text="@string/view"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:background="@android:color/white"
                        android:id="@+id/change_view"
                        android:textColor="#000"/>

                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Any one can help me how solve my problem. I am new in android developing please help me.Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at Toolbar http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Answer (score 0):

It Could be achieved by two manner.
1) Custom Header
2) Actionbar/Toolbar.

Custom header means only height attribute you have to take as`@dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height`(if you are using appcompat).
For eg. sample demo
    `

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
    android:background="#FF6600"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/menu"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_moreoverflow_mtrl_alpha"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/menu"
        android:entries="@array/array_name"
        >
    </Spinner>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_search_api_mtrl_alpha"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/star"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/star_yellow"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/search"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        />
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/shop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_copy_mtrl_am_alpha"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/star"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"

        />
</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

`
Just give it a try.